# Exercise in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

Let $\mathbb{N}^{[2]}$ be the set of all sets with two elements in $\mathbb{N}$, and let $\mathbb{N}^{[2]}=A\cup B$. Prove that there is an infinite set $M\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that either $M^{[2]}\subseteq A$ or $M^{[2]}\subseteq B$. Any ideas?

I found a hint telling to use the well-ordering principle

Comment: "the set of all sets.." sounds suspicious. If $b$ is some set with $b\cap\mathbb N=\{1,2\}$ then do we have $b\in\mathbb N^{[2]}$? If so then $\mathbb N^{[2]}$ is not a set but a proper class.

Comment: @drhab as far as i understand the question, every element in $\mathbb{N}^{[2]}$ has exactly two elements. so it is a set, even a subset of the power set of $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: $\mathbb N^{[2]}=\{\,x\in\mathcal P(\mathbb N):|x|=2\,\}$, nothing sudpicious.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen So "the set of all subsets of $\mathbb N$". Not "the set of all sets". Reason for suspicion is valid.

Comment: @supinf I agree with your interpretion. But on base of the fact that every element in it has exactly two elements you cannot conclude yet that you are indeed dealing with a set.

Comment: the meaning is the one Hagel von Eitzen gave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classical theorem of Ramsey. There are many proofs. See for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem).